# NGINX return 405 Not Allowed with PUT and DELETE method

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I get an error like this.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEbFE.png)

My nginx conf file like this.

```
upstream backendapi {
        server  192.168.1.105:3005;
            
    }

    upstream uibackend {
        server  192.168.1.105:3000;
            
    }   
    
    server {
        listen                  8090;
        server_name             mv-ua.adtest.com:8090;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    location /{
             proxy_pass         http://uibackend/;
        }
        
    location /web/ {
             proxy_pass         http://uibackend/;
        }

    location /login {
            proxy_pass      http://uibackend/;
        }
        
    location /api/ {
             proxy_pass         http://backendapi/;
        }
        
    location /health {
             proxy_pass         http://backendapi/;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

I use Nginx and I have an issue like that. On my .NET server I allow CORS but i get an Internal Server Error. How can I handle that?

Comment: Pretty sure the error comes from your backend, not nginx

Comment: There is no such thing in HTTP as a "`PUT DELETE` method".

Comment: PUT and DELETE methods

Comment: On my backend side, I already give all Access Control Allow